# Java requires slash instead of backslash on Windows in resources

Tags: java

I want to check if a file exists on resources and use this line:

```
getClass().getResource(resource.getResourceFullName()) != null
```

`resource.getResourceFullName()` is a method that returns just the file name without slashes like `testevnvariables.yaml`

I got that file did not exist. For your information, I use Windows and IntelliJ IDEA locally but prod is on Linux.

Then I tried to do this, but, again, the file does not exist:

```
getClass().getResource(File.separator + resource.getResourceFullName()) != null
```

and only when I added manually "/" I got "exists":

```
getClass().getResource("/" + resource.getResourceFullName()) != null
```

So my question is why it is happening? As far as I know, the default separator for Linux is slash, and for Windows is a backslash. File.separator returns a correct value for Windows - backslash but Java can't find it.
I don't want to add "/" manually and want to be independent of the system and use something like System.lineSeparator() but for files. How can I do it?

I also tried to use `File.exists()` but with the same result.

And why when I found a file, Idea shows me this path (with slashes like on Linux):

```
.../target/test-classes/testevnvariables.yaml
```

Comment: Resources are not (necessarily) on the file system, they are on the classpath, and resources on the classpath use `/` exclusively (also, `/` identifies the root of the classpath, not the root of the file system). It also helps to think of resources as (relative) URLs (without a protocol and host name).

Comment: Whether in windows are linux, java resource paths are expected to be in `/`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for your answer. So am I correct that if resources are in classpath then it does not matter what system is out there I can always use forward slash for resources? And as I understood then file.separator it's definitely when I want to get files from the file system and not my project (especially resources).

Comment: @NikitaPoddubskiy No, you always need to use a forward slash (`/`) for resources.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, forward slash, it was a mistake. Thanks

Comment: The argument to getResource methods **is not a file name.**  It is a *relative URL,* and URLs *always* use forward slashes, on all platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource is something on the class path, which can be considered a sort of JVM specific virtual file-system (it is comprised of all JARs and directories, etc that have been specified on the class path). The file separator for this virtual file system is exclusively `/`. So, just use `/` and you are good to go. You don't need to fiddle with `File.separator` or anything, as the `/` is already system independent.

As an aside, even on Windows, most filesystem APIs allow you to use `/` and `\`  interchangeably.